# Secret Service codenames for West Wing characters

Tags: the-west-wing

I've just finished watching Season 3 of The West Wing. In the last few episodes of that season the Secret Service have the codenames **Flamingo** for C.J. and **Eagle** for the President.

Do other characters in The West Wing have codenames, and if so, what are they?

Comment: Bob Russell's secret service code name was Bob Russell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [West Wing Wiki](http://westwing.wikia.com/wiki/Secret_Sevice_Codenames) lists code names for only four characters:
President Josiah Bartlett: Eagle
Sam Seaborn: Princeton
C.j. Cregg: Flamingo
Zoe Bartlett: Bookbag

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Service_codename#In_popular_culture) contains a few more:
President Jed Bartlet - Eagle or Liberty
Gus Westin (Grandson of Jed Bartlett) - Tonka
Arnold Vinick - Big Sur

There's also a [reddit](http://en-us.reddit.com/r/thewestwing/comments/1foyri/secret_service_code_names/), but most of these seem to be humorous, rather than authentic.

Comment: A bit of trivia to accompany this good answer -- Bill Clinton's secret service name was also 'Eagle,' reinforcing the connection that Aaron Sorkin was trying to foster between Bartlett and Clinton. Additionally, the White House communications agency always assigns secret service codenames to family members that begin with the same letter as the codename for the president ... so, for example, Hillary Clinton was 'Evergreen' and Chelsea was 'Energy.' So in The West Wing, Stockard Channing's and Elizabeth Moss's characters would have also had codenames starting with 'e.'

Comment: @jlmcdonald - Sorkin must not have been aware of this; Zoey Bartlet's codename Bookbag doesn't fit, then.

Comment: yes ... didn't see that on your list until your comment. Who would have thought that Sorkin wouldn't have been attentive to accuracy in detail. :)

Answer (score -1):

Josh was Motormouth but was renamed Phoenix after surviving the shooting.